# Узнать реальный тип объекта

Tags: c++, массивы, типы-данных

Предположим, есть тип  базовый класс SceneObject и есть производные от него классы.
Я хочу хранить массив объектов этого класса, для этого завожу vector< SceneObject*> obj.

Добавляю туда некоторые объекты производных классов.
А когда достаю их оттуда, я хочу узнать их реальный тип.
typeid(obj[i]).name() всегда выдает тип SceneObject*.
Как узнать реальный тип объекта?(

Или может быть, я все делаю неправильно.
Как тогда сделать массив объектов, производных от одного класса, чтобы потом можно было определить какой это объект?

Answer (score 3):

Информация о типе - это дополнительная информация. Когда у вас есть виртуальные функции - есть и их таблица, которая по сути и есть информацией о конкретном типе.

Без этого надо хранить информацию о типе *где-то отдельно*.

Но как вы хотите использовать эту информацию? Для чего? Обычно - без виртуальных функций - она попросту бессмысленна...

Кстати, раз уж вы пользуетесь указателями и иерархией классов - то учтите, что с точки зрения безопасности деструктор базового класса должен быть объявлен как виртуальный!

Answer (score 2):

Для определения реального типа объекта вы можете воспользоваться `dynamic_cast`:
`TYPE* dynamic_cast<TYPE*> (object);`

Comment: Для классов, не содержащих виртуальные функции, это не работает(
Может быть, можно как-то по-другому?

Comment: а тут разве не нужно знать к чему кастовать? а вопросе вроде обратный вопрос?

Comment: Да, тут нужно знать(
Но можно сделать иерархию if-else и попробовать поприводить ко всему, при некотором желании(хотя это медленно и неоптимально)

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что Вы неправильно выводите имя, должно быть так: `typeid(*obj[i]).name()`, но это будет работать лишь в том случае, когда `SceneObject` является полиморфным, т.е. содержит хотя бы одну виртуальную функцию. Это требуется потому, что без этого [RTTI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) по классу отсутствует, и оператору `typeid` просто неоткуда узнать, что же за тип ему реально передан.

Если Вы немного подумаете, то поймёте, что для того, чтобы получить информацию во время исполнения, нужно использовать какие-то средства времени исполнения. В C++ все эти вещи связаны с виртуальностью и ничем другим. Поэтому без полиморфного базового класса, боюсь, Вам задачу не решить.

Что касается правильно/не правильно. Обычно, если появляется задача узнать реальный тип данных, то это на 99% ошибка дизайна. Реальный тип практически никогда знать не нужно, для выполнения конкретной реализации существует полиморфное поведение, то есть виртуальные функции.